# How to know when the airplane shouldn't turn around

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I was taking this aptitude question, and I had this confusing math problem in it I couldn't figure out.

> An airplane is travelling 2400 miles from A to B. It is going at 600 mph with a tailwind of 40 mph. After what point in time should it have taken longer to go back to point A than to complete the route to point B?

My original answer was 2 hours, which turned out to be wrong. Anyone else knows how to solve this.

Comment: Is the airplane going 600 mph ground speed (net), *including* a 40 mph tail wind, or is it going 600 mph airspeed, *plus* a 40 mph tail wind?

Comment: I would have to say the 600 mpg would include the tail wind.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is to calculate the answer using either assumption (ground speed or air speed), to see if either yields the expected answer.

Comment: mpg? or mph?  one is speed and one is fuel use.  Traditionally, planes measure their "airspeed" (speed through the air mass) an then adjust for the wind speed.  This would suggest 600 is an airspeed, and 640 would be the ground speed.

Comment: Please tell us how you arrived at you original answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the plane is going 600 mph and that *includes* the tailwind. That means its speed is $600-40=560$ mph. So when it turns around, the the tailwind becomes a headwind and its speed becomes $560-40=520$. As it takes longer to make the return trip, the turnaround time would be *before* 2 hours (the halfway point).

Let $d$ be the distance traveled and $v$ the speed of the plane. You can find time $t$ when $t=\frac{d}{v}$. For the trip to point $B$, $t=\frac{2400-d}{600}$. For the trip back to point $A$, $t=\frac{d}{520}$. The answer you seek is when the two quantities are equal. In other words, solve for $d$.

Now assume the plane's speed is 600 mph *plus* the tailwind, for a total speed of 640. The speed on the return journey is then 560 mph. Use these values in your equation and solve for $d$. If it's a multiple choice test, only one of the answers should be among the choices.